# Reuse planks of an old garden house

Tags: wood, outdoor, pressure-treated

In my allotment garden there is an old garden house, which needs to be torn off. The house is approximately 30 years old and the planks are varnished. The wood varnish is already peeling off. I don't know whether the wood has been treated with other wood preservatives.

There is no evidence of mold or damage from woodworm and the planks are looking pretty ok for being that old.

For our vegetable patches we want to build a very simple border by embedding boards halfway into the ground. Of course I will remove the wood varnish first.

Now, I'm concerned that possible wood preservatives will be washed out of the wood by rain and absorbed by plants.

The house has not been maintained for at least 10 years.

Do you think it is save to use these planks for our vegetable patches?

Comment: I don't know about safety, so not an answer, but I have embedded old boards as borders before and they last 2 years, tops. This includes old decking, which was originally pressure treated, and rafters which were very thick. I was pretty surprised. Moisture + decomposition organisms / fungi living in the soil are pretty good at digesting wood. The borders will look lovely, but I wouldn't expect any strength.

Comment: In the US, it's unlikely that the shed (garden house) would have been made entirely of pressure treated lumber. Certain elements (Anything close to the ground, like flooring, floor joists, bottom plates that may sit directly on concrete/dirt/concrete blocks/other foundation material) _would_ likely be PT material, but the studs, sheathing and rafters would probably not be PT for cost savings. TL;DR: There probably aren't preservatives in those parts of the salvage lumber for you to worry about _unless_ building practices are different in your country.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. @FreeMan: I'm from Germany but what you wrote about cost savings makes totaly sense.

Comment: Re. the warnings about the short lifespan of pine in direct contact with soil from Walnut Close in his Answer and FreeMan in the Comment above, while this is textbook advice I wanted to add some firsthand observations. Years ago when I first started woodworking I monitored offcuts of untreated pine/spruce/fir that I'd tossed *into my compost* and was quite surprised when they didn't break down anything like as fast as most sources suggested. Even *the shavings* could be identifiable sometimes more than a year later o_O My climate will be similar to yours, and probably slightly wetter. [contd]

Comment: Based on this over the past few years I've donated short pieces of pine quarter-round moulding to my partner for use as props for various garden plants, and the ends stuck in the soil are not visibly decayed after 2-3 years!

Comment: Hallo, hast du [einen Hochdruckreiniger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YHas.jpg)?

Comment: No, I don't own a pressure washer but a hand plane ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's highly unlikely that the wood was pressure treated for a "dry" use like sheathing.   And, it would be very unusual to use an after market preservative in that setting, beyond the varnish.   So it's almost certainly just wood with some varnish on it.  Safe for the use you propose.

Putting it into contact with the ground as you propose is going to end in disappointment, however.   It's highly likely that it's pine, and 3/4" of pine stuck in the ground will rot off in a year or two.   Hardly be worth the trouble of putting it up, from a landscaping point of view.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the wood rots. I just need some kind of border for the patches and that way I don't have to throw it away but can reuse it. :)